# How to create custom django model field for representing opening and closing hours of a place

Tags: django, django-orm

I have an application about Restaurants. You can set its opening and closing time. I do it by adding two time fields like this.

```
class Place(models.Model):
    # other fields
    opening = models.TimeField()
    closing = models.TimeField()
```

However I want to do it with one, custom field something like this.

```
class Place(models.Model):
    # other fields
    operating_hours = models.DualTimeField()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want this? Do you have a database that supports such type ? If no, then how are you going to save that field to the database ? As a varchar ? If yes then how are you going to query the database for when your place opens ?

Comment: The reason is that opening and closing hours of a restaurant represents one property-operating hours of it. They are not separate. That's why I want to do it. Or, for example you may want min-max field. I can represent them as JsonField, or something else. If I had all of the answers of your questions why I've to post it in here?

Comment: I'm trying to make you understand that using a field that is not natively supported by your database *will* result in problems. Saving the open-closing hours in a varchar may seem smart right now but what will happen when you want to find out what places are open are 1am ? Or you want to find out how *many* places are open at 2 am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use a CharField and parse the string in the model via a property, e.g "hh:mm - hh:mm"

2) Use a the Django native DurationField:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#durationfield
if you want to model opening hours you need a second field to define the opening hour, it is working on the timedelta.

3) Use two TimeFields like every one else would do.

4) Another option would be a MultiSelectField where the user can select the hours of the day the place is open.

```
OPENING_HOURS = (
    (1,'1am'),
    (2,'2am'),
    (3,'3am'),
    (4,'4am'),
    ...
    (12,'12pm'),
)

class Place(models.Model):
    # other fields
    operating_hours = models.my_field = MultiSelectField( choices=MY_CHOICES)
```

See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am going to use first one.

Comment: I think the fourth option also might be interesting.

Comment: I don't think so. Because with this option user will have to select all operating hours manually.

Comment: Okay, but think a little about the queries you want to perform later on that field. A string field will produce strange effects later on. Cheers